# external monitor extremely slow with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, laptop

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop attached with a Dell monitor. My Nvidia driver version is 465.27 with a GeForce 3070 card. My external monitor becomes extremely slow when I close the laptop lid.

I read several posts:

[Ubuntu 20.04, computer keeps shutting down when I close the lid, I've already checked logind.conf, settings are set to suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277543/ubuntu-20-04-computer-keeps-shutting-down-when-i-close-the-lid-ive-already-ch)

[20.04 on external monitor (2560x1600) extremely slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244674/20-04-on-external-monitor-2560x1600-extremely-slow?newreg=759aba5fc800475a8f8bb10239914722)

[Keep Ubuntu Server running on a laptop with the lid closed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141866/keep-ubuntu-server-running-on-a-laptop-with-the-lid-closed)

[Ubuntu graphics performance slow with external monitor AND notebook lid closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829454/ubuntu-graphics-performance-slow-with-external-monitor-and-notebook-lid-closed)

And, I tried all the solutions but still not working. When I close the laptop lid, the external monitor still becomes very slow.

```
$ nvidia-smi
Fri Oct  8 13:03:13 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 465.27       Driver Version: 465.27       CUDA Version: 11.3     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P3    24W /  N/A |    105MiB /  7982MiB |     17%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1116      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 34MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2005      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 69MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Below is my /etc/systemd/logind.conf

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the integrated GPU (i.e. your Intel Evo, HD or AMD Ryzen graphics) disabled? Some ports on laptops are connected directly to the integrated GPU to facilitate seemless switching from the dedicated graphics chip to save power.

Answer (score 4):

solved it by setting IgnoreLid=true in /etc/UPower/UPower.conf, thanks!

Reference: [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I found a lot of resources saying to edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and that did not fix my problem - editing `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` is the only thing that has worked.